# Issue with Matterhorn capture agent

Tags: ubuntu

I don't know whether it is the correct platform to post my issue. 
Today i am trying to install matterhorn on Virtual private server, i have followed instructions as mentioned in matterhron site, I have succesfully installed Capture agent but when i try to run the capture agent i am facing some problems.. 
as per your reference i am pasting the problem.

```
root@ubuntu:~# sudo /etc/init.d/matterhorn start 
Starting Matterhorn as user synergy: make: Entering directory '/opt/matterhorn/capture-agent/epiphan_driver' 
make: *** No rule to make target 'load'.  Stop. 
make: Leaving directory '/opt/matterhorn/capture-agent/epiphan_driver'
```

what to do now, please help me out.

Comment: Did you install the capture agent alone? You probably also need to install the core server.